# How do I match parts (title or isbn) from my book array that was created from a text file?

Tags: java

When I run this code, it gives an error saying cannot involve get__() on the array type Book[].. In the main method, I have a book array with the information from a text file -- title, isbn, price, qty, forsale.

```
    public static int searchByTitleOrISBN(Book[] b)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //   print a message "Enter the Title or ISBN of the book: "
        System.out.println("Enter the Title or ISBN of the book: ");
        String input = scan.next();
        
    
        //   use a while loop to search through the array books using a counter and as long as no match is found
        while (i < b.length) {
        //      if there's a match for the title or a match for the isbn and the book quantity > 0 and the book is for sale
            if ((b.getTitle().equals(title) || b.getISBN().equals(isbn)) & b.getQty() > 0 && b.isForSale()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to acces an element in your loop not the array itself:

```
 while (i < b.length) {
        //      if there's a match for the title or a match for the isbn and the book quantity > 0 and the book is for sale
            if ((b[i].getTitle().equals(title) || b[i].getISBN().equals(isbn)) & b[i].getQty() > 0 && b[i].isForSale()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to search the entire list.If you want to keep up your present implementation, then the solution given by @Jens works.

But If you go by searching one by one it would be O(n) but if you leverage inbuilt HashMaps you can do it with O(1) using hashCode and equals and no need of looping through all the objects for each and every search.

the Book class which keeps the data of the book. hashCode and equals is implemented here.

```
public final class Book{
    private final String title;
    private final String isbn;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean forSale;
    public final Key key;

    public Book(String title, String isbn, double price, int quantity,boolean forSale){
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity =quantity;
        this.forSale = forSale;
        this.key = makeKey(title,isbn);
    }
    
   private static Key makeKey(String title,String isbn) {
       return new Key(title,isbn);
   }
   
   public Key getKey() {
       return this.key;
   }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getISBN(){
        return this.isbn;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString(){
        String s = this.title +"; "+ this.isbn+ "; "+this.price+"; "+this.quantity;
        return s;
    }
    
    public static final class Key{
        private final String title;
        private final String isbn;
        
        private Key(String title,String isbn) {
            this.title = title;
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }
        
        private String getTitle() {
            return this.title;
        }
        private String getISBN() {
            return this.isbn;
        }
    
        //calculates the hash of the entry, if we don't override this it will
        //use the hash of the reference. so we need to change it for comparision
        @Override
        public final int hashCode(){
            return this.title.hashCode()+this.isbn.hashCode();
        }

        //if two components have same hash code, then we can use extra criterion
        //to check if the two objects are same. in the book case the hash is
        //unique.since we are using the title and the isbn;

        @Override
        public final boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(this==obj){
                return true;
            }
            if(obj!=null && this.getClass()==obj.getClass()){
                Key tempObj = (Key)obj;
                return (this.title == tempObj.getTitle()) && (this.isbn == tempObj.getISBN());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

BookMap class which stores all the book objects in form of  Map<Book.Key,Book>. This will help with the easy retrival of book data.

```
public final class BookMap{
private final Map<Book.Key,Book> map;
private final String name;

public BookMap(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.map = new HashMap<>();
}

public final String getName(){
    return this.name;
} 

public final Map<Book.Key,Book> getMap(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.map);
}

public final void addBook(Book book){ 
     this.map.put(book.getKey(),book);
}

public final Book getBook(Book book){ 
    Book.Key tempKey = book.getKey();
    return this.map.get(tempKey);
    
}

public final boolean findBook(Book book){
    if(book != null) {
    return this.map.containsKey(book.getKey());
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public final String toString() {
    String s ="Books list : \n";
    for(Map.Entry<Book.Key,Book> b:this.map.entrySet()) {
        s= s+b.getValue()+"\n";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Now a sample Main.js with static main method to retrieve the book list.

```
public class Main {
public static BookMap list = new BookSet("General list");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book temp = new Book("Journey to the center of the earth","isbn-001-002-0455",9.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("The Time Machine","isbn-001-002-0456",9.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("The War of the Worlds","isbn-001-002-0457",8.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("Brave New World","isbn-001-002-0458",11.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("Ninteen Eighty-four","isbn-001-002-0459",19.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("Ray Bradbury","isbn-001-002-0460",14.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("I, Robot","isbn-001-002-0461",12.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("Foundation","isbn-001-002-0462",12.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("The Martial Chronicles","isbn-001-002-0463",3.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    temp = new Book("Fahrenheit 451","isbn-001-002-0464",6.99,15,false);
    list.addBook(temp);
    
    //testing with the book already in the list;
    temp = new Book("Fahrenheit 451","isbn-001-002-0464",0,0,false);
    //prints book detail
    System.out.println(list.getBook(temp));
    
    //testing with the book already in the list;
    temp = new Book("I am not in the list","isbn-001-002-0464",0,0,false);
    //prints null as the book is not in the list
    System.out.println(list.getBook(temp));
    
    System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

The above is a rough idea, you can develop more on it, i have used final for classes in order to prevent subclassing, as it would become complex with inheritence to understand and debug.i like avoiding complexity as much as i can. If some common pattern is there, then i will try to use abstract classes.